# passing parameter to a jar file which is called in a bat file?

Tags: java, batch-file, executable-jar

I have created a jar which needs to be called in a bat file. I need to pass all the command line arguments recieved by bat file to the jar. Can anyone please help me out. I know this is a stupid question, but i dont have any idea about jar and bat. On net i am unable to find the combination of both. Also note that i dont know how to retieve the command line arguments in the bat file.

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside you bat file you will have `java` command
just use `java -jar helloworld.jar firstParam secondParam` and 
I believe you can also use because that how we pass params to `Maven` and `ANT` etc

```
mybatchFile.bat -DfirstParam -DsecondParam
```

Comment: You mean `java -jar helloworld.jar firstParam secondParam`, right?

Comment: ok... are you sure no need to give the main class as Andreas said?

Answer (score 8):

The parameters that you pass to your batch file can be accessed via

```
%1 %2 %3 ...
```

So if you call your batch like

```
C:>application.bat param1 param2 param3
```

then your java call inside the batch file should look like:

```
@echo off
java -cp app.jar com.example.Main %1 %2 %3
```

Comment: but how do you do you do this in a generic way, i.e you dont know how many parameters the users could pass to the batch file (if any)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many parameters the users could pass to the batch file (if any) you need to get the no. of arguments whatever the user has passed, simply add the following snippet to your main method at the start

```
for (String s : args) {
    // Iterate through String array in Java (args list)
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

You can store all the arguments in an Arraylist to use it and iterate over it later

Comment: From the question, OP is working with a bat file, not within java code...