# Need help providing parameter while batch file execution in perl script

Tags: java, perl, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have to execute a abc.bat file in a perl script.

If I run the  batch file manually it  asks for first param at first step. When I provide this at second step it will ask for second param..

I need to call this abc.bat file in a perl script

Something like..

> system(‘abc.bat’); or  exec()

But how to provide param run time..

The abc.bat batch file is a calling a java  myclass  which takes two params at runtime.

Below is the batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal
set classpath=.\my.jar;%classpath%
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java com.myclass
@echo on
```

Please help .. Thank you.

Comment: any one could you please help me on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426653/passing-parameter-to-a-jar-file-which-is-called-in-a-bat-file

Its better to pass at batch file level itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use the %ENV variable to do everything directly in perl? Maybe:

```
$ENV{classpath} = ".\\my.jar;$ENV{classpath}";
system("$ENV{JAVA_HOME}\\bin\\java com.myclass");
```