# java run program using different credentials

Tags: java, authentication, executable-jar

I want to run my executable jar with different Functional user credential and share that with my colleagues to use it (without sharing username & Password).

I have tried RUNAS but there is no way to pass password in that command.
Option /savecred won't do it for me as after system restart it prompts for the password and wrong attempts could lock the functional account.
Any suggestions?
P.S.  I need a programmatic fix. Using any tool from market is not an option.

Comment: Are you using a batch file to run the jar

Comment: yes, but if you have any other better approach please suggest

Comment: Then pass your user id as command line arguments from the batch file and use that in your main class...

Comment: userid is not a problem.  can do it with simple dos command as well. It's about passing the password. Also I couldn't find any java code to launch my program with different credentials.

Comment: Set the password too from the batch file only

Comment: Could you please share some example.   Also note that I can't just write the password in batch file. Whole point of doing this is to not to share credential.       what I have in my mind is get the credentials username and password(encrypted) from a config file, decrypt the password (using java)  and launch the program.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426653/passing-parameter-to-a-jar-file-which-is-called-in-a-bat-file will tel you how to set them but you are right the main point is to not to share the credentials.. looking for it wait

Comment: You can do this... Make a main class that has a jframe form that asks for user id password and from that run your projects main class...

Comment: Thanks but I guess I am not very clear with my query. Reading credential is not an issue.  The solution you suggested is another graphical version of what I am able to do from Command prompt as well.       Main challenge I have is to launch the program with different credential.

Comment: Store your userid and passwords in a map and then check their validity from the map upon user input... It will work

Comment: I am sorry but you are totally on different track.   question is about launching a program with different credentials, not validating some credential or reading it.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84668/akash-kumar... meet me here and explain i would like to help

Comment: Thanks but recently I started using this forum and to chat 20 reputation is criteria, which I don't have.